# Flutter Duplicate GlobalKey detected in widget tree error

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile

```html
class Login extends StatefulWidget {
  const Login({super.key});

  @override
  State<Login> createState() => _LoginState();
}

class _LoginState extends State<Login> {
  bool passwordVisible = true;

  void iniState() {
    super.initState();
    passwordVisible = false;
  }

  final _emailController = TextEditingController();
  final _passwordController = TextEditingController();
  GlobalKey<FlutterPwValidatorState> validatorKey =
      GlobalKey<FlutterPwValidatorState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text('Login'),
        ),
        body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
          child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                TextFormField(
                  controller: _emailController,
                  decoration:
                      const InputDecoration(hintText: 'Endereço de email'),
                ),
                const SizedBox(
                  height: 20,
                ),
                TextFormField(
                  controller: _passwordController,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      suffixIcon: IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(passwordVisible
                            ? Icons.visibility
                            : Icons.visibility_off),
                        onPressed: () {
                          setState(() {
                            passwordVisible = !passwordVisible;
                          });
                        },
                      ),
                      hintText: 'Palavra-passe'),
                  obscureText: passwordVisible,
                ),
                FlutterPwValidator(
                  key: validatorKey,
                  controller: _passwordController,
                  minLength: 6,
                  width: 400,
                  height: 60,
                  onSuccess: () {
                    return true;
                  },
                  onFail: () {
                    return false;
                  },
                ),
                ElevatedButton(
                  onPressed: () async {
                    bool greenSign = false;
                    bool validateEmail =
                        EmailValidator.validate(_emailController.text);
                    if (validateEmail == true) {
                      greenSign = await login(
                          _emailController.text, _passwordController.text);
                      if (greenSign == true) {
                        SharedPreferences pref =
                            await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
                        pref.setString("id", employee.id!);
                        Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                                builder: (context) => const HomePage()),
                            (route) => false);
                      }
```

I'm building a simple flutter app, and I'm some facing some issues.

I saw many others posts about this issue, but most of them did not solve my problem.

I'm using GlobalKey to navigate properly between pages on my app.

But when I logout with a user and try to login again with another user, flutter throw me these issues 'Duplicate GlobalKey detected in widget tree'.

To logout and login I'm using 'pushAndRemoveUntil' mt

Here's my code from logout:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9tui.jpg)

Here's my code from login:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcZfn.jpg)

Here's my code registering GlobalKey
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iqANg.jpg)

I apreciate every response.

Comment: post code snippets not code images, this stack overflow is a markdown editor

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post the complete code of your `Login` page, but i would assume it also has your `NavigationService.navigatorKey` inside of it like your `HomePage` and this is causing your error.

This is because during the page transition of navigating the widgets of both pages are mounted and you may not have multiple widgets with the same global key mounted at the same time.

So this is because you get your error when navigating from `Login` to `HomePage`, or the other way around.

TLDR: don't use the same global `GlobalKey` on different Pages which you navigate between with a `Navigator`.

Comment: I posted now my login page, it does not have my NavigatorKey

Comment: But are you using the navigator key in the enclosing material app, or navigator that is above the login page? Or where are you getting your `Navigator.of(context)` from?

Comment: I'm using the navigator key in the enclosing material app

Comment: Yes, this leads to the duplicated keys (because of the inner `MaterialApp` of your `HomePage`. If you remove the inner `MaterialApp` of your `HomePage`, then your error will go away if you don't use duplicated keys anywhere else.

Comment: There's not another way to overcome this problem? I can't just remove MaterialApp from my HomePage, it'll break the entire structure of my application.

Comment: What do you need it for? You already have your top level `MaterialApp` which provides your Navigator with the navigatorKey and you can provide different themes with the help of 
`Theme(data: themeData, child: child,);`

Comment: I'll try to use another approach, thanks!

Comment: No problem, let me know if you need help, or an example!

Comment: From now I deleted that navigatorKey, I think there's not a specific reason to use it.